# Access web page and download *.ext files, where ext can be set python script

Tags: python, parsing, url, urllib2

I have a python script that downloads a specific file that I specify via URL, and i'm wondering if there is a nice way to access a page, and grab every file that ends in a certain extension.

Example:
Go to a page with a few .py files, some .pdf files, and some .jpg files, along with text and other links.
Then download to your current directory all of the .py files.

Here's what I have now that just grabs a specific file that I choose:

```
import urllib2
import sys
import httplib
from urlparse import urlparse
import numpy

if numpy.size(sys.argv) == 1:
    print 'Need a command line argument -- Quitting'
    quit()
urlin = sys.argv[1]
url = "http://"+str(urlin)

def checkUrl(url):
    p = urlparse(url)
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(p.netloc)
    conn.request('HEAD', p.path)
    resp = conn.getresponse()
    return resp.status < 400


if checkUrl(url)==False:
    print 'Website is not active'
    quit()
else:

    file_name = url.split('/')[-1]
    u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    f = open(file_name, 'wb')
    meta = u.info()
    file_size = int(meta.getheaders("Content-Length")[0])
    print "Downloading: %s Bytes: %s" % (file_name, file_size)

    file_size_dl = 0
    block_sz = 8192
    while True:
        buffer = u.read(block_sz)
        if not buffer:
            break

        file_size_dl += len(buffer)
        f.write(buffer)
        status = r"%10d  [%3.2f%%]" % (file_size_dl, file_size_dl * 100. / file_size)
        status = status + chr(8)*(len(status)+1)
        print status,

    f.close()
```

Is there a way to extend this to do what I initially mentioned?

EDIT:
Ideally I'd like to be able to use relatively standard python packages, but i'm not totally opposed to odd packages.
I also know that I can download the page that the links are on, and parse the HTML for strings ending in *.ext, and then go back and download those extensions by tacking them to the end of the original URl, but i'm not good at file parsing it python.

Comment: You could use [this](https://gist.github.com/elssar/5160757). Just replace `pdf` with `exe`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) for downloading the Urls, and [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for parsing the pages to find more URLs to download.

This is incomplete, but something like:

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = requests.get(url)
req.raise_for_status()

html_doc = req.text.encode(req.encoding)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)

links = soup.findAll(href=re.compile("\.pdf$"))

for link in links:
    req = requests.get(link)
    # here, you'll want to use r.content, since it's probably a binary file
    content = req.content
    # write the bytes to a file
```